# Java MongoDB search for value in multiple fields

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mvc, mongotemplate

i have a java method

```
 public List<Project> tagSearch(String searchCriteria){
    Query query = new Query();
    return mongoTemplate.find(query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("projectTag")
            .regex(searchCriteria,"i")), Project.class, COLLECTION_NAME);
}
```

here it is searching the searchCriteria value in the field projectTag. I want to search for that value in multiple fields. for example another field projectName

appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Use [orOperator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Criteria.html#orOperator(org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria...))

You can use as many criteria in orOperator. Then it will look like this :

```
Query query = new Query();
Criteria criteria1 = new Criteria().where("projectTag").regex(searchCriteria, "i");
Criteria criteria2 = new Criteria().where("projectName").regex(searchCriteria, "i");
query.addCriteria(new Criteria().orOperator(c1,c2));
return mongoTemplate.find(query, Project.class, COLLECTION_NAME);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code

```
final Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.orOperator(Criteria.where("projectTag").regex(searchCriteria, "i"),
                    Criteria.where("projectName").regex(searchCriteria, "i"));
final Query query = new Query(criteria);
final List<Project> projectEntities = mongoTemplate.find(query, Project.class);
```